# Python's preferred comparison operators

Tags: python, comparison

Is it preferred to do:

```
if x is y:
    return True
```

or

```
if x == y
    return True
```

Same thing for "is not"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`x is y`  is different than `x == y`.

`x is y` is true if and only if `id(x) == id(y)` -- that is,  `x` and `y` have to be one and the same object (with the same `id`s).

For all built-in Python objects (like strings, lists, dicts, functions, etc.), if `x is y`,  then `x == y` is also True. However, this is not guaranteed in general. Strictly speaking, `x == y` is true if and only if `x.__eq__(y)` returns True.

It is possible to define an object `x` with a `__eq__` method which always returns False, for example, and this would cause `x == y` to return False, even if `x is y`.

So the bottom line is, `x is y`  and  `x == y` are completely different tests.

Consider this for example:

```
In [1]: 0 is False
Out[1]: False

In [2]: 0 == False
Out[2]: True
```

PS. Instead of

```
if x is y:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

it is more Pythonic to write

```
return x is y
```

And similarly,

```
if x == y:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

can be replaced with

```
return x == y
```

Comment: I'm being a bit picky, but it's not correct that you need `x == y` to be true before `x is y` can be true. They are independent tests. Admittedly in practice you'd be hard-pressed to find a sensible counter-example, but the `__eq__` special method could just return `False` or raise an exception.

Answer (score 15):

`x is y` compares the identities of the two objects, and is asking *'are `x` and `y` different names for the same object?'* It is equivalent to `id(x) == id(y)`.

`x == y` uses the equality operator and asks the looser question *'are `x` and `y` equal?'* For user defined types it is equivalent to `x.__eq__(y)`.

The `__eq__` special method should represent 'equalness' for the objects, for example a class representing fractions would want 1/2 to equal 2/4, even though the 'one half' object couldn't have the same identity as the 'two quarters' object.

Note that it is not only the case that `a == b` does not imply `a is b`, but also the reverse is true. One is not in general a more stringent requirement than the other. Yes, this means that you can have `a == a` return `False` if you really want to, for example:

```
>>> a = float('nan')
>>> a is a
True
>>> a == a
False
```

In practice though `is` is *almost* always a more specific comparison than `==`.

Answer (score 9):

- **`==`** and **`!=`** are object *value* comparison operators
- **`is`** and **`is not`** are object *identity* comparison operators

as others have already said, **`is`** (and **`is not`**) are only when you actually *care* that a pair of variables are referring to exactly the same object. in most cases, you really don't care at all, so you would use **`==`** and **`!=`**.

however, what you may start to notice, if you look at a lot of Python code, is that **`is`** (and **`is not`**) are more likely to be used when comparing against `True`, `False`, and `None`. the main reason for this is that those objects are singletons, meaning there is exactly one instance of each of those values. why does that matter? well, this leads to another reason... speed.

with **`==`** and **`!=`**, the interpreter has to pull up both referred objects in order to make a comparison (of whether they're the same or not), while **`is`** and **`is not`** simply just check the values of the objects they're referring to. with this said, you can see that  the latter pair will perform faster because you don't have to fetch the objects themselves in order to make the comparison. here's a speed test from a couple of years back where we concluded that for one-offs, it's not a big deal, but if it's called a gazillion times in a tight loop, well, it will start to add up.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-June/062708.html

bottom line is that you can use object identity comparisons for checking against `True`, `False`, and `None`, and everything else should use straight-up equality operators. we won't get into interned integers nor bound instance methods, or anything like that here. :-)

Comment: Good point about comparing to singletons. On the subject of speed it's worth noting that `if a == True:` is slower than `if a is True:` which in turn is slower than just `if a:` (at least for built-in types in my tests). Often just using `a` or `not a` is the quickest option although they're not quite semantically the same as `a is True` or `a is None` etc.

Comment: So, what about comparing ints, like `1 is 1` or `1 == 1`?

Comment: altho they're both equivalent when using small ints (currently) in the `range(-5, 256)`, those are not publicized numbers and can change in any release, so it's safer just to use `==` in all cases except `None`, `True`, and `False` (and perhaps a few others).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't count on *None* being a singleton.  In PyDev, an environment where you can have many objects and many layers of inheritance, and especially in PyUnit where the code is run by a test runner, there are cases where *x is None* will fail, but *x==None* will work as expected.  Same thing with strings.

Comment: Yep, this only applies to CPython not executing in IDEs where anything goes. Thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

Depends. `is` and `is not` do identity comparison, which is good for `None`, `Ellipsis`, or making sure that two objects are the same. Otherwise, use `==` or `!=`.