# Python 3 REGEX .finditer: Usefulness of hex address in "callable_iterator object at 0x..."?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

The following Python 3.5 prints `add_date_iter == <callable_iterator object at 0xb78e218c>`.

```
import re

date_added_attrs = re.compile(r'( +ADD_DATE=)("(\d+)")')

add_date_iter = date_added_attrs.finditer(test_string)
print("add_date_iter ==", add_date_iter)
```

So far, so good. BUT of what use is `0xb78e218c`? It appears to be a hexadecimal memory or object address. Whatever it is, why / how if at all might a Python 3 program make use of it?

---

**EDIT:** My question is NOT about REGEX. The REGEX works fine. My question is, what's the purpose / benefit of the hexadecimal value returned by the *.finditer* operation?

Comment: Well what is your goal of using regex here?  Can you also include sample input along with the output you want to see?

Comment: The REGEX works just fine. That's not my question. My question is, why is what appears to be a hexadecimal value included as part of the callable iterator returned by the successful REGEX finditer operation?

Comment: You are trying to print the _iterator_.  That's not what an iterator is used for.  Again, what is your actual goal here?

Comment: When you print this particular Python object, you happen to get a memory address where the iterator resides, this is all you are seeing here.

Comment: Great. That's part of the answer I was looking for. So how -- if at all -- might that memory address be used? Or is it just something included for "fun"?

Comment: No, that's just part of the standard `__repr__` inherited from `object.__repr__`. It is helpful when you are maybe debugging things, but isn't supposed to be used for anything. So just check out `print(object(), object(), object())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the purpose / benefit of the hexadecimal value returned by the .finditer operation?

When you write `print("add_date_iter ==", add_date_iter)`, you are simply converting the iterator object to a string and printing it. That is, `<callable_iterator object at 0xb78e218c>` is the return value of the object's internal `__str__` method.*

The hexadecimal address is telling you where in memory the iterator is stored. It is the same value you would get if you ran `hex(id(add_date_iter))`. It is generally only useful when you're trying to figure out the internals of how Python is managing memory during a [certain process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference), or if you want to check whether two variables are holding a reference to the same object. When comparing objects, you can think of `id(a) == id(b)` as a [long way of writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6235702/1174966) `a is b`.

#### More detail...

For instance, if you had this code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

a = A()
b = A()

print(id(a), id(b))
print(a is b)

b = a

print(id(a), id(b))
print(a is b)
```

You would get an output like this:

```
140665126149392 140665230088528
False

140665126149392 140665126149392
True
```

In the first case, even though the instance variables `val` have the same value, the objects themselves are different. After writing `b = a`, though, both variables now refer to the same object.

One place you can get tripped up with this is with [integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40930822/1174966), which is why you should always use `==` instead of `is` unless you really know what you're doing (or you're checking `is None`, since `None` is actually a [singleton object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504780/1174966)):

```
a = 5
b = 5
a is b # True

a = 300
b = 300
a is b # False
```

One final point: since Python has [first class functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392402/what-is-first-class-function-in-python) (i.e. functions are treated as objects), everything discussed above works with functions, too. Just reference the function without parentheses, like `id(print)`.

*  Note: If you write `add_date_iter` without `print` in the interactive shell, it will call the `__repr__` method instead

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I learned more than one thing for sure...