# When to use == and when to use is?

Tags: python, memory, equality

Curiously:

```
>>> a = 123
>>> b = 123
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = 123.
>>> b = 123.
>>> a is b
False
```

Seems `a is b` being more or less defined as `id(a) == id(b)`.  It is easy to make bugs this way:

```
basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
if ext is '.mp3':
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Some fnames unexpectedly ended up in the else block.  The fix is simple, we  should use `ext == '.mp3'` instead, but nonetheless `if ext is '.mp3'` on the surface seems like a nice pythonic way to write this and it's more readable than the "correct" way.

Since strings are immutable, what are the technical details of why it's wrong?  When is an identity check better, and when is an equality check better?

Comment: *related:* [Python '==' vs 'is' comparing strings, 'is' fails sometimes, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is the \`==\` operator not equivalent to the \`is\` operator? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647692/when-is-the-operator-not-equivalent-to-the-is-operator-python)

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2577589/674039

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `is` checks for object identity equivalence. As there's no compulsory "string interning", two strings that just happen to have the same characters in sequence are, typically, not the same string object.

When you extract a substring from a string (or, really, any subsequence from a sequence), you will end up with two different objects, containing the same value(s).

So, use `is` when and only when you are comparing object identities. Use `==` when comparing values.

Comment: Actually, there _is_ string interning. It just won't happen for dynamically created strings.

Comment: @katrielalex there is a builtin `intern()` which lets you *explicitly* intern dynamically created strings; it just doesn't happen by itself.

Comment: @katriealex: I think I actually meant "automatic and compulsory string-interning" (there are, I believe, some languages that do do that).

Comment: @Duncan: I think the compiler automagically interns string literals that appear in the source, though. And @Vatine: ugh :p

Comment: @katrielalex The compiler automatically interns strings in the source if the content of the string could be a valid Python identifier. Other strings are not interned, but duplicate strings in a single compilation unit will still be shared (but not shared with other compilation units). All of which is of course an implementation detail and subject to change at any time.

Comment: @duncan, @katriealex It is still pretty unlikely that the result from os.path.splitext would ever be is-identical to a static string, though (even if it compares equal using ==).

Comment: @Duncan [`intern()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#intern) no longer exists on Python 3.

Comment: @Boris it does but it moved to `sys.intern()`

Comment: So when is identity comparison required/preferred over value equality check?

Answer (score 23):

They are fundamentally different.

1. `==` compares by calling the `__eq__` method
2. `is` returns true if and only if the two references are to the same object

So in comparision with say Java:

1. `is` is the same as `==` for objects
2. `==` is the same as `equals` for objects

Answer (score 18):

**Simple rule for determining if to use is or == in Python**

Here is an easy rule (unless you want to go to theory in Python interpreter or building frameworks doing funny things with Python objects):

Use is only for `None` comparison.

```
if foo is None
```

Otherwise use ==.

```
if x == 3
```

Then you are on the safe side. The rationale for this is already explained int the above comments. Don't use is if you are not 100% sure why to do it.

Comment: They Python way is readable code, meaning use `==` as long as that's what you mean (almost always). `is None` `if x:` `if not x:` is Python convention to check for `None True False` respectively. Real use of `is` comes when you examine complex data structures, e.g. `assert not [l for l in mylist if l is mylist]` a simple check against cycles in (plain) data structure.

Comment: what about types? `type("foo") is str` is probably ok

Comment: types are checked using `isinstance`, e.q. `isinstance("foo", str)`, or, if you want to exclude subclasses, `type("foo") == str` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

It would be also useful to define a class like this to be used as the default value for constants used in your API. In this case, it would be more correct to use is than the == operator.

```
class Sentinel(object):
    """A constant object that does not change even when copied."""
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        # Always return the same object because this is essentially a constant.
        return self

    def __copy__(self):
        # called via copy.copy(x)
        return self
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be warned by PyCharm when you use `is` with a literal with a warning such as `SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?`. So, when comparing with a literal, always use `==`. Otherwise, you may prefer using `is` in order to compare objects through their references.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is missing a clear example of when to actually us `is` when comparing objects that are not `None`.

Several objects, e.g. lists, when assinged to other variables retain the object reference instead of creating a copy of the object. This may lead to undesired behavior if not properly understood:

```py
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a[0] = 0
>>> b
[0,2,3]
>>> b is a
True
>>> b == a
True
```

However, if you create multiple instances of the same object they have the same definition but are essentially different objects:

```py
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a[0] = 0
>>> b
[1,2,3]
>>> b is a
False
>>> b == a
True
```

When is comes to `None`, it is a special case. `None` is a singleton object, thus, instantiantion of `None` is restricted to one object. Therefore testing if an object is `None` with the `is` operator always works.

```py
>>> a = None
>>> b = a
>>> b_ = None
>>> a is None
True
>>> b is a
True
>>> b_ is a
True
>>> b_ == a
True
>>> b == None
True
```

In conclusion, use `is` whenever you want to find out that both variables point to the exact same object, that is, if you change the state of `a`, `b` will be changed as well.

Comment: “Several objects, e.g. lists, when assinged to other variables retain the object reference instead of creating a copy of the object.” — This is incorrect: **all** objects retain their object reference when assigned to another variable.