# Partially apply a string equality function

Tags: python, string-comparison, functools

From what I understand I can compare strings with `is` and `==`. Is there a way I can partially apply these functions?

For example:

```
xs = ["hello", "world"]
functools.filter(functools.partial(is, "hello"), xs)
```

Gives me:

```
functools.filter(functools.partial(is, "hello"), xs)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `is` is not a function. Neither is `==`.

Comment: What do you mean by partially ? What is your aim ?

Comment: You should [always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570371/when-to-use-and-when-to-use-is) compare strings with `==`. Comparing object with `is` checks for identity, and should only be used for singletons like `None`.

Comment: There are functions like `str.startswith("target")` and `str.endswith("target")` as well as testing for a string within another by `str.find("target") > -1` but it depends on what exactly you need to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`operator.eq`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html):

```
import operator
import functools
xs = ["hello", "world"]
functools.filter(functools.partial(operator.eq, "hello"), xs)
```

yields

```
['hello']
```

`operator.eq(a, b)` is equivalent to `a == b`.

Comment: There's also [operator._is](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html#operator.is_).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would want to use partial here. Much easier to write it directly as a function, for instance by using lambda:

```
functools.filter(lambda x: x == 'hello', xs)
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question I asked.