# If my function returns list index, what should it return if position does not exist

Tags: python

I wrote a function that returns the index of an item in a list if that item exists, otherwise return False

```
def student_exists(ID):
    for student in students:
        if student.id == ID:
            return students.index(student)
    return False
```

But then I realised that it can be an issue later since later in my code I did something like this:

```
if student_exists(ID) == False
```

which will be true if the function returned index 0.

What can I use instead of false to represent the item not existing in the list?

Comment: You could throw an exception. You could return -1, you could return None.

Comment: Your function name is misleading, suggesting it should just be returning the boolean in the first place

Comment: If you expect your function to only return an index (an integer), it can even return a random string and then you can check the type...

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you'd want to return the index. Chances are you're going to use the index to reference the *students* list. So why not return a reference to a *student* object or None if it's not found?

Comment: @ArthurKing, ive been avoiding using the object since it looks like this: `<__main__.Student at 0x1e2fc667e20>`, and is more confusing for me when debugging. Is there a reason for me to reference the actual object rather than its position in the list?

Comment: @S12312 It depends on how you're going to use it

Comment: @ArthurKing I have a list, and ive used this function to find the student in the list (if it exists) before doing things like modifying/deleting/adding

Comment: @S12312 If *that* is your problem with returning the instance itself, then see [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/6045800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `None` if the item does not exist.

When you return `None`, you will avoid the location 0 problem. Note that when trying to ask if something is `None` you should use: `if x is None`.

Note that the `is` operator should be used for checking `None`, otherwise you can experience unexpected behavior (see ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/6045800))

Comment: interesting. Can i use that for other comparisons as well? like this: `if x is 7:`

Comment: @S12312  you can but with a warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
def student_exists(ID):
    for student in students:
        if student.id == ID:
            return students.index(student)
    return None
```

Or you can retrun index that is not normally returned, such as -1:

```
def student_exists(ID):
    for student in students:
        if student.id == ID:
            return students.index(student)
    return -1
```

Comment: I should probably stay away from -1 in case later in the code I make a mistake and use it as an index. None seems to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Observe how Python handles situations like this:

```
>>> string = "hello world"
>>> print(string.find("w"))
6
>>> print(string.find("z"))
-1
>>>
```

As you can see, the `str.find()` method returns `-1` when the substring is not found in the string. So you can do

```
def student_exists(ID):
    for student in students:
        if student.id == ID:
            return students.index(student)
    return -1
```

Another good option would be to use `None`. But when checking if the output is `None`, use the `is` keyword rather than the `==` operator:

```
if student_exists(ID) is None
```

Comment: That's just one example. [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) on the other hand raises an exception

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sure, that's why I used `str.find()` as an example rather than `str.index()`. The OP asked *what* their function should return, not *whether* or not is should return anything at all :)

Comment: Just saying... If we inspect how Python handles things, raising an exception is another possible approach...

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can leave the function as it is, and simply use the return value differently. Instead of `if student_exists(ID) == False` do:

```
if student_exists(ID) is False
```

See [When to use == and when to use is?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6570371/6045800)

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> False is 0
False
```

---

Just because no one else even mentioned it, the way your function is implemented is not so efficient/optimal and is doing one extra unnecessary pass of the list. You are looping over the list to find a matching element, but then `index` will loop the list again behind the scenes. Instead, you should [Access the index in 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/6045800):

```py
def student_exists(ID):
    for i, student in enumerate(students):
        if student.id == ID:
            return i
    return False
```

Comment: @AnnZen */faceslap/* You're totally right! Don't know what I was thinking. You are correct that it is `O(N*2)` (==`O(N)`) and not `O(N^2)`. Thanks for the correction. Will edit :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in an earlier comment, returning an index into a list is not a good idea. Better, IMO, to return a reference to the object itself (or None if it can't be found).

Allow me to elaborate...

Let's assume that our student class looks like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, id_):
        self.name = name
        self.id_ = id_
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Student: name={self.name} id={self.id_}'
```

...and that we have a global list of students...

```
students = [Student('Arthur', 100),
            Student('Lancelot', 101)]
```

Now we need a function to search the list for a student with a specific id:

```
def find_student(student_list, id_):
    for student in student_list:
        if id_ == student.id_:
            return student
```

Then this is how we can bring everything together:

```
for i in [100, 101, 102]:
    if (student := find_student(students, i)):
        print(student)
    else:
        print(f'Student {i} not found')
```

Which will give this output:

```
Student: name=Arthur id=100
Student: name=Lancelot id=101
Student 102 not found
```

**Notes:**

Note the trailing underscore for the student id variable (id_). This is to avoid any possible conflict with the builtin *id* function.

Added a repr dunder function to the class to facilitate simple printing of a class instance.

Even though the student list is global, it's better to pass a reference to the *find_student* function. After all, somewhere else in the code you might have another list of students. This makes the function reusable.

And finally, this is the wrong way to maintain a list of students. Assuming their IDs are unique then a dictionary is more appropriate and has the added benefit of making a lookup much easier and faster. If the IDs are not unique then the *find_student* function could give unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this one of the ways used by `@Ruli`.

There is some information for you :
0 and an empty string is always `False`

```py
if 0: #==> False
    print('Yes') #This line of code is not executed because the above expression is False.
```

```py
a = ''
if a:# False
    print('Yes') #This line of code not execute because the above expression is False.
```

The way I do is:

```py
def student_exists(ID):
    for student in students:
        if student.id == ID:
            return students.index(student)
    return False

output = student_exists(ID)
if output == False and output != 0:
    # write your code here.
```

Comment: That is really unintuitive and should be avoided...

Comment: So you're going to call *student_exists* twice to determine whether or not to execute some code? That's not a great idea

Comment: @ArthurKing see the updated code.

Comment: @SharimIqbal In order to not define a variable you can also do `if 0 != student_exists(ID) == False`

Answer (score 0):

Behavior when searching for an item in a collection of some kind, and the item is not found, is quite varied across Python.

In the standard library:

- looking up an index that doesn't exist in a list or dictionary raises an exception
- [`next(item for item in iterable if meets_criterion(item))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-that-matches-a-condition) raises an exception unless a default value is specified
- `dict.get` returns `None` by default
- [`bytearray.index`, `bytes.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#bytes.index), `str.index` and `list.index` raise an exception. (Having `list.index` return `None` would be a problem in case the list actually contains `None`.)
- [`bytearray.find`, `bytes.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#bytearray.find) and `str.find` return -1
- [`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=find#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find), [`re.match`, `re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=find#re.Pattern.search) return `None`

External modules commonly return `None`, e.g. BeautifulSoup `find`, Google App Engine [`Model.get_by_id`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/modelclass), MongoDB [`find_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one). Raising an error might be more logical in some cases, but returning `None` is probably more convenient, avoiding the need for a lot of `try...except` blocks.

In your case, I would rename your function something like `get_student_by_id` and return `None` if it is not found.

Answer (score -1):

Use `None` and `enumerate`

```py
def student_exists(ID):
    return {s.id: index for index, s in enumerate(students)}.get(ID)

if student_exists(ID) is None:
    ...
```