# The significance of == 0 in python. (Beginner)

Tags: python

I am very new to coding, I found something very confusing in python for me.

In this small piece of code:

```
if (count % 4) == 0 and (count % 6) == 0:
    print ("Cheesecrackers")
    count = count + 1

elif (count % 4) == 0:
    print("Cheese")
    count = count + 1

elif (count % 6) == 0:
    print ("Crackers")
    count = count +1

else:
    print (count)
    count = count + 1
```

The line:  if (count % 4) == 0 and (count % 6) == 0: 
Why does the addition of "==0" make a difference to how the code runs?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Open a Python console, and write `1 % 4`, `2 % 4`, `3 % 4`, `4 % 4`, `5 % 4` etc. See what results you get. Once you get to at least `8 % 4` I'm sure you will start to see the pattern... :) And once you do, you should hopefully start to understand what the comparison against `0` is for.

Comment: `%` is modulo operation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

your `==`  is checking if result of Modulo is `0` or not.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect that "if x is zero" means something different from "if x" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's preferred comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576826/pythons-preferred-comparison-operators)

Answer (score 2):

`== 0` means the remainder is zero of the two numbers.

As `x % y` gives the remainder of `x / y`, you can say `y` goes into `x` evenly if there is no remainder (ie the remainder is 0). However, `x % y` will not always equal zero. For instance `3 % 2` gives 1. Thus the `== 0` is checking that the remainder computed by `count % 4` and `count % 6` is zero (no remainder)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count % 4) == 0:
```

In the if-else statement, these are conditions or cases that are being tested. So in this case, it is testing if count % 4 has a remainder of 0 (happens when count is perfectly divisible by 4).

If you omitted the '==0', the if statement will just test if the outcome exists regardless of whether it is perfectly divisible or not.

Similarly,

```
if count:
```

will also always evaluate to True as long as the variable count exists.